# Wrong Mime-Type when downloading binary file on mobile data (Android)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to download a binary file using:

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
ucon.connect();
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(ucon.getInputStream());
```

When run via mobile data (on Samsung Galaxy 4, Android 5.0.1) I receive the following response

```
j���UFEHLER��6ERROR��`Заявеното съдържание не може да бъде заредено ��&Wrong MIME-Type���Fback��2
```

Which means "The content requested cannot be loaded" in Bulgarian (the server I download from is Bulgaria). But more informative seems "**Wrong MIME-Type**" at the end of the response.

I tried the same using `HttpGet` with no result. 
The weird thing is everything is ok when I execute the same request via Wifi. 
Also I can download the file from the brower on mobile data, but not for the code. Also I've tested on Lenovo with Android 4.4.2 via mobile data and is also worked.

I noticed I'm getting `Content-Type: application/vnd.wap.wmlc` (logged `ucon.getResponseCode()`) when connected via mobile data and nothing set as content type when via WiFi.

Any ideas? :/

Comment: also i tried `ucon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");` but again i got the same rasult

Comment: Post more code and did you try Postman to simulate the download?

Comment: yes, i  did the same request from Postman and I was working ok. now i tried to capture the traffic with tPacketCapture and the file download did worked the the capturing was active but otherwise it did not. 
this problem occurs only when I'm trying to download a `.dat` file. I can successfully download `.xml` and `.jpg` from the same server.

Comment: You can have a look at these links. 1. http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/   2. http://martinkabraham.blogspot.com/2013/11/android-browser-file-down-load.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working code for file downloading. You can have a look to check if you're missing something.

```
public class ImageDownloaderAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    private static File f;

    protected void doInBackground() throws IOException {

        File dir = new File(Constants.FILE_PATH);
        if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();
        f = new File(Constants.FILE_PATH + Constants.FILE_NAME);

        if (f != null && !f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();
        }

        try {
            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();

            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            String data1 = f.getPath();
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(data1);

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                }
                stream.write(data, 0, count);      
            }
            stream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            doInBackground();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {}
}
```

Comment: still not working :/ i'm getting the same response Wrong MIME-Type